# How to get other languages in translatableResources?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm working with translations in Shopify API. I have English set as the default language, but now I've also added Portuguese as a language and published it (I haven't added any translations though).
However, when I call the GraphQL translateResources, it only returns the translatable content for English.

I'm using postman. This is my query

```
    query getTranslatableResources {
  translatableResource(resourceId: "gid://shopify/Product/7276207800399") {
    resourceId
    translatableContent {
      key
      value
      translatableContentDigest: digest
      locale
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the translatableContent object I get in the response:

```
"translatableContent": [
                {
                    "key": "title",
                    "value": "Cartridge Medium Taper Gauge 10 Tight Liner 5 needles (More than 10 month validity)",
                    "translatableContentDigest": "a73b0b1ad55fc98ab46fb1d41dcb10f7877747c4dc8ed5798129cce398cf0f30",
                    "locale": "en"
                },
                {
                    "key": "body_html",
                    "value": "test",
                    "translatableContentDigest": "9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08",
                    "locale": "en"
                },
                {
                    "key": "handle",
                    "value": "needle-3",
                    "translatableContentDigest": "deff7e9e149736d4e3ab2e3a1e8268c2015a9a4f54f42b67224dbd0e0f73b91c",
                    "locale": "en"
                },
                {
                    "key": "product_type",
                    "value": "",
                    "translatableContentDigest": "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855",
                    "locale": "en"
                }
            ]
```

As you can see, I have added and published Portuguese as a language.

[image: Shopify languages]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TranslatableResource object](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/objects/TranslatableResource) only contains the resource's Global ID and the translatable content. It doesn't resolve to the [product object](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/objects/Product) itself, which is where you would be able to see it's translations.

For the product in your example, you would need to query it directly or use the node interface, and then provide the locale as an argument to the translations field:

```
{
  node(id:"gid://shopify/Product/7276207800399"){
    ... on Product{
        translations(locale:"pt-PT"){
        locale
        key
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the translations object is always empty (no matter which locale I provide) and even if it returned the translations correctly, it won't return the digest so I can add other translations, correct?

Comment: Have you added translations in the admin or with the [translationsRegister](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2024-01/mutations/translationsRegister) mutation?

Are there any userErrors in the response to that mutation?

Comment: I followed [this guide](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/selling-strategies/markets/translate-content) the other day and the steps worked

Comment: That helped! I see what the issue was, when I was using translationsRegister, I was passing the locale as "pt", rather than "pt-PT". I figured that out using the link you provided, by calling shopLocales, but I see you added it to your answer too. I also thought it was supposed to show all translations in the translatableContent, but as you said it only shows the default one, so the query above helped as well to retrieve the Translations I added. Accepted it as the solution! Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. 
I just googled the Portuguese locale and thought it was "pt" at first too.